# Jquery toggleclass not working, following the example nearly word for word

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, this, toggleclass

I'm fairly new to Jquery, hence the noob questions......

Iv been trying to follow this to toggle a class on and off when a user clicks a link, iv got it now so that if the user clicks a link with lets say id="22" it will tick the tickbox with id="tick_22", what I'm trying to do now is add some user feedback so that the link changes colour when the tick box is ticked. I have tried to follow the example on the Jquery site http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/
, but for some reason its not working ?. I'm not sure if I need to use (this.class) or just (this) ?.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.selectlink', function () {
         var myId = $('#check_' + this.id);
         if ($(myId).is(':checked')) {
         $(myId).prop('checked', false);
         $(this).toggleclass( activeselectlink, addOrRemove );
         }
         else {$(myId).prop('checked', true);
         $(this).toggleclass( activeselectlink, addOrRemove );
         }
         countChecked();
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: `toggleClass`... and I don't mind you practicing `toggleClass` but you can also use css `.selectlink:active{color:red}` for styling an active element or `.selectlink:focus{color:red}` for a focused one :)

Comment: The problem with css is if the user clicks the link again to disable the text box the link will still show as being clicked.

Comment: please share your html also

Comment: and the value of `activeselectlink` and `addOrRemove ` and how it is change

Comment: @lainSimpson, yup, didn't notice the scenario much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the class to toggle in `"class2toggle"`:

```
$(this).toggleClass("activeselectlink"); // this should work
```

Answer (score 3):

check your case, Javascript/jQuery use Camel case..i.e. name it toggleClass and not toggleclass .. http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: did you print/console.log this.id ? I suggest better use jQuery.data() function to find related id instead of this method.

Answer (score 1):

case is wrong.

Check for it first :

.toggleClass instead of .toggleclass

Answer (score 0):

First its `.toggleClass()` not `.toggleclass()`.

Second, the variable `addOrRemove` has not been declared anywhere. It is supposed to be a variable of type boolean.